# Laravel Eloquent query builder no relation on wrapped 'where'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-7

I have made a [package for searching models with JSON input](https://github.com/asseco-voice/laravel-json-search) which has a `search` macro exposed on Eloquent models.

While trying to wrap a query, I noticed a strange behavior, so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

For example, loading the relation like this:

```
Builder::macro('search', function () {
    return $this->with('someRelation');
});
```

results in all models with their relation being loaded, all looking good.

Wrapping it within additional `where` clause causes it to load only models and no relation whatsoever:

```
Builder::macro('search', function (array $input) {
    return $this->where(function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->with('someRelation');
    });
});
```

Why doesn't this work? How to make it load relation while wrapped within an outer `where`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't explain the specifics of why it doesn't work, but I'd imagine one of the following two options will fix it:

```
Builder::macro('search', function (array $input) {
    return $this->where(function (Builder $builder) {
        return $builder->with('someRelation'); // note added 'return'
    });
});
```

or

```
Builder::macro('search', function (array $input) {
    return $this->where(function (Builder $builder) {
        // return whatever
    })->with('someRelation');
});
```

Comment: I already tried returning it, it doesn't do anything. Chaining `with()` on the original Builder object (`$this`) works, but then it is not wrapped within `where()`...then it is the same as my first example

Comment: Can I ask why you want to use the where function? If you just want the relation, then it seems unnecessary, unless you want to specify other conditions. I think `with()` has to be on the same level as `where()` to work

Comment: This is a minor extract of logic I'm doing, it's not as trivial as it looks. I need to wrap it within `where()` because if I do an inner `orWhere()` I am opening my app to a security breach.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand why you need the `with()` inside a `where()`. If you're trying to eager load relations for only specific instances of the model you're retrieving, then take a look here, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know how eager loading works, thanks :D If you take a look at the package maybe you get the grasp of the complexity and why I might need it, although the question is not why I need it, but why doesn't it work.